# Pull extended properties from Microsoft Graph Security API?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-security, azure-sentinel

I am trying to pull the base events related to an alert no Sentinel via API, however Graph Security API really doesn't return much. I am unable to see mapped entities or the extended properties.

I've tried using the "expand" option in url to expand the properties but no luck. Honestly I really don't see a lot of info in Graph API that I would normally see in a search.

Also, is there a way for the for me to find the base events of a search from the alert id?

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/security/alerts/{alert
>   id}?$expand=extendedproperties
>
> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/security/alerts/{alert
>   id}?$expand=extended
>
> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/security/alerts/{alert
>   id}?$expand=properties
>
> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/security/alerts/{alert
>   id}?$expand=extensions

[image]

Comment: May I know what extended properties are you looking for?

Comment: The extended properties field in the screenshot (from running a native search in GUI of Log Analytics), it has the Analytic rule id, and the query related to the security Alert. I mostly want that Query field to be returned by the API.

Answer (score 1):

The alert properties including extended properties from multiple security providers (Azure Sentinel is one of them) are mapped to a common schema of Graph Security API. The details of the Query field in Azure Sentinel may appear under different fields in Graph Security alert. If any of the fields aren't there, then they will be added in the product roadmap as we are continuing enriching the alert contextual information.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use https://api.securitycenter.microsoft.com/api/alerts ?
I'm guessing it's being deprecated, but that's where I see more complete information on alerts. The /alerts endpoint in Graph is still missing some information.